# How would a modern city defend against dragons which glow in X-ray and emit electromagnetic pulses?

Tags: science-based, warfare, apocalypse, dragons, modern-age

Tens of thousands of dragons (as big as B2 bomber and top speed clocking  at Mark 0.5) mysteriously appears above New York City. They are docile in nature, but these creatures pose a serious threat to our modern technology. Their bodies glow in X-ray. Also, every second, their body emits powerful electromagnetic pulses. The frequency of the pulses varies and could only be block by an ideal Faraday cage that could never exist in reality. Miraculously, the dragons themselves are not affected by these emissions. Unless we do something, their presence will disable electronic circuitry and sterilize anything within close proximity of 100m radius. Note the dragons will turn aggressive when provoked (easily detected when they begin to salivate fluoroantimonic acids...).

How can New York defend against such creatures?

Comment: Faraday cages won't stop x-rays - unless such a cage is very thick. And even then it doesn't need to be a Faraday cage, just a thick shield.

Comment: EMP is not a type of radiation, it's a mixture of several pulses of electromagnetic fields. AFAIK high-energy EMPs can so far only be produced by nuclear explosions.

Comment: After reading it a few times, I made a guess on how to clarify the question, based on the description of the destruction. @user6760 -- is the edit correct?

Comment: @SRM: yes that's perfect now no one can stand in its way!

Comment: half a point for flouroantimonic acid! For those interested: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroantimonic_acid

Comment: How big are these dragons? Sparrow or Jumbo jet?

Comment: Over NYC? I think King Kong and Spider Man can handle them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Find out what makes them tick

If the dragons emit electromagnetic pulses (EMPs) in a [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) setting then they must have a [science-based](/questions/tagged/science-based) way to do so (as opposed to magic).

This  can be used to your advantage. By killing a few of the smaller dragons, and promptly dissecting them, you can identify the processes responsible for this mechanisms. You can look for the organs that create the pulses, and try to find a counter-pulse or some way of rendering it unusable, then apply it on a larger scale.

It may mean shooting the dragons below the necks, or turning off the city's power grid and detonating an EMP of your own - I can't go into detail, because the question does not specify how the dragons work. However, there is likely a way to stop them from functioning.

Answer (score 0):

### Lure them away to contain them

There is no logistically feasible way to protect the city.
Redesigning the city's infrastructure, or making all circuitry resistant to EMPs is simply not feasible on such an enormous scale. Luckily, the acid actually won't be a huge problem: it reacts violently with water, and at high altitudes, any application of the saliva will be surrounded by water vapor. Most of the acid will dissolve into less dangerous compounds before it hits the ground.

1. Keep everyone indoors, away from the windows, and at the lowest floor possible. That radiation is harmful.
2. Reinforce an armada of state-owned helicopters with radiation shielding; collect a lot of drones.
3. Get some pretty big, pretty thick nets, and slaughter a whole lotta cows.
4. Use the drones to lure the smallest dragons away from the city, using flashing lights and raw meat. It may take a lot of trial and error, but it's cheaper than some alternatives.
5. Use the helicopters with nets and larger portions of meat to herd the larger specimens. If dragons do not cooperate, they can be shot down, but it would be ideal to keep some alive to study.
6. The hordes can be brought to a secure location, somewhere with quite thick walls, and then the dragons can sedated via a gas system that had been in construction as soon as they heard about the dragons. This may be miles away from the city, but unless you want to lure them all over the North Atlantic and shoot them, this is your best bet to study them.
7. Shoot the stragglers / those who could not be moved to a secure location.